# How Can I Keep 14 Days of Logs using Logrotate?

Tags: linux, logging, error-logging, logrotate

I want to change my logrotate.conf file to compress and save the last 14 days worth of system log files. Will these setting work if placed in my configuration file?

```
  rotate 14
  compress
  extension log
  create 640 www-data users
}
```

Comment: What log rotation program do you use? A dedicated one, or is it built into the logging daemon? What logging daemon do you use, maybe it can do it for you?

Comment: @datenwolf I believe this is built into the logging daemon and is run via cron.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand what each parameter of `logrotate` does, for debian you can find the info [here](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/logrotate/logrotate.8.en.html)

Here you are confusing rotate count with maxage, the rotate *count* specifies that log files are rotated *count* times before being removed or mailed to the address specified in a mail directive.
e.g.

```sh
# sample logrotate configuration file
compress
/var/log/messages {
    rotate 5
    weekly
    postrotate
        /usr/bin/killall -HUP syslogd
    endscript
}
```

The first few lines set global options; in the example, logs are compressed after they are rotated. The next section of the config file defines how to handle the log file `/var/log/messages`. The log will go through **five weekly rotations** before being removed.

The option you are looking for is **maxage** *count*

### maxage

Remove rotated logs older than *count* days. The age is only checked if the logfile is to be rotated. The files are mailed to the configured address if maillast and mail are configured.